# Skip NA in Mean function within Pandas agg function

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my working code:

```
new_df = old_df.groupby('store', as_index = False).agg({'reviewScore': 'mean'})
```

I would like to add an argument to the mean function: `skipna=True`

I can't figure out the syntax to make it happen.

Do I need to learn how to use lambda functions?

Comment: From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#na-values-in-groupby): "*NA groups in GroupBy are automatically excluded*".

Answer (score 5):

`NaN` values are skipped automatically. For example if we have the following table:

```
  store  reviewScore
0     a          4.0
1     b          3.0
2     a          3.0
3     a          NaN
4     b          5.0
```

`groupby` and find `mean` for each group:

```
df.groupby('store', as_index = False).agg({'reviewScore': 'mean'})
```

what is equivalent to:

```
df.groupby('store', as_index = False).mean()
```

Output:

```
  store  reviewScore
0     a          3.5
1     b          4.0
```

To use arguments in aggregation functions you can utilize a `lambda` function:

```
df.groupby('store', as_index = False).agg({'reviewScore': lambda x: x.mean(skipna=True)})
```

or

```
df.groupby('store', as_index = False).agg(lambda x: x.mean(skipna=True))
```

The result should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The internal `mean()` function will ignore NaN values.

The only scenario well you get NaN, is when NaN is the only value. Then, the mean value of an empty set, gives NaN.

Aggregate functions `agg` work in the same way as `mean()`.